# Definition of a symbol $s_{NN}$ appearing in particle physics

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics, terminology, collision

1. What is the meaning of $s_{NN}$ in particle physics?

See e.g. here
http://www4.rcf.bnl.gov/brahms/WWW/thesis/karabowicz_phd_thesis.pdf
page 18 in the pdf.

2. What is its relation to energy?

I need a definition for a beginner in particle physics.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $s_{NN}$ is in OP's context of [RHIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Heavy_Ion_Collider) the [Mandelstam $s$-variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelstam_variables) in a Nucleus+Nucleus collision. The $s$-variable is also known as the square of the center-of-mass energy.